# How to minus two dates in Activerecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I want a list of contracts that are dues in 3 days time. Thus, I am writing a query that find the difference between the current date and the date that are stored in my COntractDue database.

Here is my code:

```
   @contract_dues = ContractDue.where("status = 'Unpaid' 
      || status =  'Partially Paid'").
      where("(due_date - #{Date.today}) = 3").
      group(:contract_id).order(:due_date)
```

I know this is wrong as I didn't get the result that I want. Any suggestion?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Alexey's approach would be better, as your method generally prevents indexes from being used to find the small proportion of contracts that you want. Does your due date have a time component on it? That woukd make things more tricky

Comment: Also change your first where clause to: "where(:status = ['Unpaid', 'Partially Paid']) and preferably put that in a scope.

Comment: @DavidAldridge hey, yeah i'll definately agree and it works great! but couldnt get your suggestion to work. I got this: " syntax error, " unexpected '=', expecting ')' "

Comment: @DavidAldridge oh, dont worries as I have figured it out. Just need to change "=" into "=>" : .where(:status => ['Unpaid', 'Partially Paid'])

Comment: @ryzalyusoff Oh yeah. well done! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of subtracting a difference, you may construct required date and compare against it:

```
.where(due_date: 3.days.from_now.to_date)
```